# How to add items to a wiki page library in Sharepoint via Web Services?

Tags: web-services, wiki, 2007

Well, the title says it all, There is not information around about this, the only link I found related to this problem, is:

http://sites.google.com/site/sharepointwikiuploader/

and it doesn't really helps. Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help.

An example using the object model (which may work for you using the Client Object Model in 2010):

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-wiki-pages/

Some information on the web service:

http://sharepoint-sandbox.com/index.php?/SharePoint-2010/Services/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.addwikipage.aspx

Comment: Hey.. Sorry, but sharepointOverflow did not notify me about your reply. I'll take a look to those links.. Thanks!